# Nginx and PHP-FPM with subdirectory variable - sends file instead of parsing

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, directory

Wit the following setup I don't know how to make nginx pass the CGI request to the index script in the appropriate version subdirectory. It instead serves the index as a download.

PHP-FPM is a linked docker container.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    root /var/www/html/public;
    server_name _;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    index index.html index.htm index.debian-default.html index.php;

    location ~ /(?<version>v.*)/ {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /$version/index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass php-fpm:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
}
```

If I nest the proxy location block and change script filename into:

```
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/$version/$fastcgi_script_name;
```

when querying `http://localhost/v1/` I get

```
nginx_1       | 2021/05/19 07:19:28 [error] 29#29: *3 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream, client: 172.26.0.1, server: _, request: "GET /v1/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://172.26.0.2:9000", host: "localhost:9081"
nginx_1       | 172.26.0.1 - - [19/May/2021:07:19:28 +0000] "GET /v1/ HTTP/1.1" 404 27 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:88.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/88.0"
php-fpm_1     | 172.26.0.3 -  19/May/2021:07:19:28 +0000 "GET /v1/index.php" 404
```

in the `nginx` and `php-fpm` logs respectively.

Comment: What is the `php-fpm` address?

Comment: @Paul it's the linked docker container. It's perfectly ok.

Comment: and 172.26.0.2:900 can be accessed?

Answer (score 0):

Using the hint in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29239775/397872), I changed the nginx config to

```
location ~ /(?<version>v.*)/ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /$version/index.php$is_args$args;

    location ~ ^(.*\.php)(.*)$ {
        ...
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$1;
        ...
    }
}
```

and it started to work as expected.

Answer (score -1):

Your *fastcgi_param* should be:

```
fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
```

if you're running php-fpm locally. If you're running php-fpm as a socket:

```
fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
```

be sure to replace *php7.3* part with your php version.

Comment: No. `php-fpm`is a valid hostname. This is not an issue. The issue is with `$version` parameter from first location block and how to pass it to the proxy block.